# It is now 2018 - Is Activity onStop killable (Not guarantee to be called)

Tags: android

now is 2018.

All the while, I save my application data during `onPause` instead of `onStop`, because I hold a strong believe `onStop` is not guarantee to be called.

Source : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[image]

> for those methods that are marked as being killable, after that method
>   returns the process hosting the activity may be killed by the system
>   at any time without another line of its code being executed. Because
>   of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent
>   data (such as user edits) to storage.

Basically, the table tells

1. For device honeycomb and above, `onPause` is not killable. It is guarantee to be called.
2. For all devices, `onStop` is killable. It is **not** guarantee to be called.

---

But, below the table, another line of text broke my strong believe.

> Starting with Honeycomb, an application is not in the killable state
>   until its onStop() has returned.

I read the same sentence many times. It means `onStop` is not killable?! This some how contrary with the above table information.

### Further reading

I read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onpause to find out the truth

> For this reason, you should not use onPause() to save application or
>   user data, make network calls, or execute database transactions; such
>   work may not complete before the method completes. Instead, you should
>   perform heavy-load shutdown operations during onStop().

It suggests us to save application data during `onStop`. Does that mean `onStop` is always called?

---

My questions are

1. Is `onStop` always called? (For Android 4 and above)
2. Should application data save operation be performed during `onPause` or `onStop`?

Answer (score 2):

You're misreading the documentation table and/or the snippet after it.

> for those methods that are marked as being killable, **after that method returns** the process hosting the activity may be killed by the system

`onPause()` is marked as killable pre-Honeycomb, and `onStop()` is marked as killable for all API levels. So this means that pre-Honeycomb, your app is killable after `onPause()`, and on Honeycomb+ your app is killable after `onStop()`. This is why they say

> Starting with Honeycomb, an application is not in the killable state until its onStop() has returned.

Comment: I agree with you but the docs are contradicting (may be typo). `Note the "Killable" column in the above table -- for those methods that are marked as being killable, after that method returns the process hosting the activity may be killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed. Because of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage.`

Comment: So what I understand is that, if you are doing any kind of I/O (async) operation to save your data in onStop(), it's a red flag because that operation could get killed in action!

Comment: @eCDroid Isn't it also a problem if you do an async operation in onPause(), because the operation is also not guaranteed to be finished before onStop() finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the app crashes, onStop will always be called.

Comment: But, why does the table in documentation says `onStop` is killable?

Comment: Killable doesn't mean that it will be hard stopped.  It means that the OS can choose to end the process for resources.  The appropriate lifecycle methods will still be called in doing so.  The foreground app will never be killed, which is why you're unkillable from onCreate (because you're about to come to the front) through onResume (because you're in front) and then become killable again when you're offscreen.

Comment: `>>  It means that the OS can choose to end the process for resources.` Isn't that mean it is not always being called? The reason I say so because once I place my application saving code in onStop. Then, a few users complains that they are experiencing data loss problem. Only then, I realize `onStop` is not always being called. But, the documentation in Android is confusing and contrary with each others.